# GDI+ Viewport optimization

Tags: c++, winapi, frameworks, gdi+

I am using GDI+ to create a simple graphics framework which allows you to use various components (Like Windows forms or java swings) to interact with the application.
Currently I am trying to implement a proper rendering system. I ran into a problem where I am unable to determine an optimized approach for Viewports.

What I am trying to achieve is not allowing the graphics of the component to be rendered outside the bounds of its parent.

I could not find any inbuilt support for handling viewports so I am forced to do the implementation on my own. My current idea is assigning a unique DC to each graphics component and then merging them together to create a final image. This would allow me to copy only the parts of the image that are within the bounds of the parent component.
Since I could not find any proper materials delving into this topic, I am not sure if the approach I mentioned is correct.

I would appreciate any suggestions / tips how viewports are standardly handled in application frameworks.

Comment: Refer [SetViewportOrgEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setviewportorgex),  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/redrawing-in-the-update-region) is sample.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are doing it wrong. The idea behind viewports is that you render whatever you have into a `back buffer` and then clip from it using viewport, like you would use a window in real life to look outside. There is no need to mess around with bunch of "hidden" `DC`s. That obviously have its own limitations, since you assume that everything is visible you have to render content of everything and then clip it depending on what is visible through `viewport`. This however can be mitigated by propagating viewport region into "internal" view, but it require a little bit more math.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only problem I see with your suggestion is differentiating between multiple viewports. In my case, basically, every component has its own viewport. Once everything is drawn on the backbuffer, I don't see a way of knowing what graphical object belongs to which component.